# How can I run dependency install job only when it's not cached or package.json changed in gitlab ci?

Tags: caching, gitlab-ci, npm-install

I have a monorepo in gitlab with angular frontend and nestjs backend. I have package.json for each of them and 1 in the root. My pipeline consists of multiple stages like these:

```
stages:
  - build
  - verify
  - test
  - deploy
```

And I have a job in a `.pre` stage which installs dependencies. I would like to cache those between jobs and also between branches, if any of `package-lock.json` changed, but also if there are no cached `node_modules` currently.
I have a job that looks like this:

```
prepare:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - npm run ci-deps # runs npm ci in each folder
  cache:
    key: $CI_PROJECT_ID
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - frontend/node_modules/
      - backend/node_modules/
    only:
      changes:
        - '**/package-lock.json'
```

Now problem with this is that if cache was somehow cleared or if I didn't introduce changes to `package-lock.json` with first push I won't have this job running at all and therefore everything else will fail because it requires `node_modules`. If I remove `changes:` from there, then it runs the job for every pipeline. Of course then I still can share it between jobs, but if I do another commit and push it takes almost 2 minutes to install all the dependencies even though I didn't change anything about what should be there... Am I missing something? How can I cache it in a way so that it only will reinstall dependencies if cache is outdated or doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I figured that I could do this without relying on gitlab ci features, but do my own checks like so:

```
prepare:
  stage: .pre
  image: node:12
  script:
    - if [[ ! -d node_modules ]] || [[ -n `git diff --name-only HEAD~1 HEAD | grep "\package.json\b"` ]];
      then
      npm ci;
      fi
    - if [[ ! -d frontend/node_modules ]] || [[ -n `git diff --name-only HEAD~1 HEAD | grep "\frontend/package.json\b"` ]];
      then
      npm run ci-deps:frontend;
      fi
    - if [[ ! -d backend/node_modules ]] || [[ -n `git diff --name-only HEAD~1 HEAD | grep "\backend/package.json\b"` ]];
      then
      npm run ci-deps:backend;
      fi
  cache:
    key: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_PROJECT_DIR'
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - frontend/node_modules
      - backend/node_modules
```

The good thing about this is that it will only install dependencies for specific part of the project if it either doesn't have node_modules yet or when package.json was changed. This however will probably be wrong if I push multiple commits and package.json would change not in the last one. In that case I can still clear cache and rerun pipeline manually, but I will try to further improve my script and update my answer.

Comment: I'm sure this can be done with Gitlab features somehow? Perhaps using workflow or rules definitions? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules.  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow 

Have you updated this perhaps later on?

Comment: @trainoasis I decided not bother, in the end I am satisfied with how it works, I didn't manage to do it with gitlab features and didn't want to spend more time

Answer (score 6):

Rules:Exists runs before the cache is pulled down so this was not a workable soluton for me.

In GitLab v12.5 we can now use [cache:key:files](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cachekeyfiles)

If we combine that with part of Blind Despair's conditional logic we get a nicely working solution

```
prepare:
  stage: .pre
  image: node:12
  script:
    - if [[ ! -d node_modules ]];
      then
        npm ci;
      fi
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
      prefix: nm-$CI_PROJECT_NAME
    paths:
      - node_modules/
```

We can then use this in subsequent build jobs

```
# let's keep it dry with templates
.use_cached_node_modules: &use_cached_node_modules
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
      prefix: nm-$CI_PROJECT_NAME
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    policy: pull # don't push unnecessarily

build:
  <<: *use_cached_node_modules
  stage: build
  image: node:12
  script:
    - npm run build
```

We use this successfully across multiple branches with a shared cache.

Comment: This is what I'm using although it would be great if there was some way to skip the step entirely. It still takes about 2 minutes to run setup which in my case includes installing node and unpacking the cache if it exists (and then re-uploading it) which seems wasteful.

Comment: what if you need different node modules for different branches? that would use same cache for all of them as you said. using  $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_PROJECT_DIR instead of nm-$CI_PROJECT_NAME should solve this problem ?

Comment: It is handled automatically thanks to using package-lock.json as the cache key. Different node modules means a different lock file meaning a different cache. If you use $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG then 2 branches with the same package lock will use different caches.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and I was able to solve it using the keyword `rules` instead of `only|except`. With it, you can declare more complex cases, using `if`, `exists`, `changes`, for example. Also, this :

> Rules can't be used in combination with only/except **because it is a replacement for that functionality**. If you attempt to do this, the linter returns a key may not be used with rules error.
>
> -- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

All the more reasons to switch to `rules`. Here's my solution, which executes `npm ci` :

- if the `package-lock.json` file was modified

OR

- or if `node-modules` folder does not exists (in case of new branches or cache cleaning) :

```
npm-ci:
  image: node:lts
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_PROJECT_DIR
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm ci
  rules:
    - changes:
        - package-lock.json
    - exists:
        - node_modules
      when: never
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: This works perfectly for branches, but for some reason, I can't get it to work when I merge. Completely skips my "Setup" job. 

Comment: I seem to remember seeing a special configuration for merge request, as they're excluded by default. Can't find it though :(

Comment: @Max haven't tried yet, but if I understood correctly:  the above will only work with direct pushes to the branch, not when MRs happen? why?

Comment: @trainoasis I'm not sure of what I said anymore, it seems wrong. Maybe I misunderstood this https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/merge_request_pipelines/ ? Sorry about that...

Comment: Just to clear up some confusion here. Rules:Exists will not work here as it is calculated before the job starts and before the cache is pulled.

Comment: @Calummm is correct, plus the usage of `rules` is wrong here. An additional step with `when: always` would be required at the end, otherwise Gitlab just falls through and will _not_ add the job. This should not be the top answer, it is very misleading.

Comment: @Pikaro I seem to remember that a rule without a 'when' clause was defaulting to 'always', but I can't find definitive proof. In my example, the rule 'changes' would apply.